# Expanding standard deviation of all columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe:

```
     a  b  c
day         
1    2  2  8
2    1  2  2
3    7  2  3
4    2  9  7
5    4  6  4
```

I want to get a new column ("std") with the expanding standard deviation of all column values. NaNs should be ignored.
This is the expected output:

```
     a  b  c       std
day                   
1    2  2  8  2.828427
2    1  2  2  2.339278
3    7  2  3  2.346524
4    2  9  7  2.782635
5    4  6  4  2.542090
```

For example, 2.339278 is equal to numpy.std ([2,2,8,1,2,2])

I tried the following:

```
df['std']  =  df.reset_index().groupby('day').expanding().std()
```

but resulted in the following TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more faster approach basing on *expanding* of a flattened array:

```
df['std'] = (pd.Series(df.values.ravel()).expanding(3)
             .std(ddof=0).dropna()[::3].values)
```

---

```
     a  b  c       std
day                   
1    2  2  8  2.828427
2    1  2  2  2.339278
3    7  2  3  2.346524
4    2  9  7  2.782635
5    4  6  4  2.542090
```

---

Time execution comparison:

```
In [223]: %timeit pd.Series(df.values.ravel()).expanding(3).std(ddof=0).dropna()[::3].values
242 µs ± 2.56 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [224]: %timeit df.stack().expanding().std(ddof=0).groupby(level=0).last()
664 µs ± 17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [225]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: np.std(df.loc[:x.name].values), axis=1)
617 µs ± 15.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [226]: %timeit df.stack().expanding().std(ddof=0)[:, 'c']
427 µs ± 1.78 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is `stack` + `expanding` + `std` + index every third value, but it means you compute also stds for intermediates:

```
df["std"] = df.stack().expanding().std(ddof=0)[:, 'c']
```

`df`:

```
     a  b  c       std
day
1    2  2  8  2.828427
2    1  2  2  2.339278
3    7  2  3  2.346524
4    2  9  7  2.782635
5    4  6  4  2.542090
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are NaNs in the data, the example should also be made that way.
If there are NaNs, use groupby

**Example**

```
data = {'a': {1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 7, 4: 2, 5: 4},
 'b': {1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 9, 5: 6},
 'c': {1: 8.0, 2: 2.0, 3: None, 4: 7.0, 5: 4.0}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).rename_axis('day')
```

`df`

```
    a   b   c
day         
1   2   2   8.0
2   1   2   2.0
3   7   2   NaN
4   2   9   7.0
5   4   6   4.0
```

**Code**

```
df['std'] = df.stack().expanding().std(ddof=0).groupby(level=0).last()
```

`df`

```
    a   b   c   std
day             
1   2   2   8.0 2.828427
2   1   2   2.0 2.339278
3   7   2   NaN 2.487469
4   2   9   7.0 2.891995
5   4   6   4.0 2.614715
```